# Is shear stress a vector?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, vector-fields

i searched and most of sources said that shear stress is a scalar quantity. But if it is scalar why do we calculate wall shear stress in 3 dimensions using below formulae.

wall shear stress (WSS) is defined as total amount of shear force per unit area.
[1]

and shear stress components in the fluid are:

$τ_{xy}=μ[∂u/∂y+∂v/∂x]$ ,
$τ_{yz}=μ[∂v/∂z+∂w/∂y]$ ,
$τ_{zx}=μ[∂u/∂z+∂w/∂x]$

WSS=$√(τ_{xy}^2+τ_{yz}^2+τ_{zx}^2 )$

I mean it feels like calculating vector resultant.

1.Gutierrez RA, Crumpler ET. Potential effect of geometry on wall shear stress distribution across scaffold surfaces. Ann Biomed Eng. 2008 Jan;36(1):77-85. doi: 10.1007/s10439-007-9396-5. Epub 2007 Oct 25. PMID: 17963042.

Comment: The quote is missing a lot of context, starting with the definition of the WSS acronym. Where is the quote from? (i.e. provide a full bibliographic reference, down to the page). And, while we're here, please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stress is a $2^{nd}$-order tensor quantity $\mathbb{T}$.

We can evaluate the elementary force $d\mathbf{f}$ acting on an elementary surface with area $d S$ and unit normal vector $\mathbf{\hat{n}}$ as

$d\mathbf{f} = \mathbf{\hat{n}} \cdot \mathbb{T} dS = \mathbf{t_{n}} dS$,

with $\mathbf{t_{n}}$ being the stress vector, with dimension of force per surface.

The constitutive law of fluids writes the stress tensor as the sum of a hydrostatic contribution due to pressure $-p\mathbb{I}$ and a viscous contribution $\mathbb{S}$,

$\mathbb{T} = -p\mathbb{I} + \mathbb{S}$.

Using this expression of stress tensor, we can write the stress vector as the sum of two contributions

$\mathbf{t_{n}} =\mathbf{\hat{n}} \cdot \mathbb{T} = -p\mathbf{\hat{n}} \cdot \mathbb{I} +\mathbf{\hat{n}} \cdot  \mathbb{S} =-p\mathbf{\hat{n}} + \mathbf{s_{n}}$.

As we can see, any contribution of the stress vector parallel to the surface may only comes from the viscous part, $\mathbf{s_{n}} = \mathbf{\hat{n}} \cdot  \mathbb{S}$, since only $\mathbb{S}$ contains out-of-diagonal (shear) components.

The constitutive law of Newtonian fluids writes the viscous stress $\mathbb{S}$, as a linear function linear of the first-order space derivative of the velocity field,
so that, for homogeneous isotropic fluids, viscous contribution reads

$\mathbb{S} = 2 \mu \mathbb{D} + \lambda (\nabla \cdot \mathbf{u})\mathbb{I}$,

being $\mu$ and $\lambda$ the two viscosity coefficients, and $\mathbb{D}$ the velocity deformation tensor

$\mathbb{D} = \dfrac{1}{2}\left[ \nabla \mathbf{u} + \nabla^T\mathbf{u}\right]$.

We can manipulate the expression of the viscous stress to write it as the sum of its isotropic (proportional to the identity tensor) and deviatoric (trace free) contributions, as

$\mathbb{S} = 2 \mu \mathbb{D}^d + \left( \dfrac{2}{3}\mu + \lambda \right) (\nabla \cdot \mathbf{u})\mathbb{I}$,

being

$\mathbb{D}^d = \mathbb{D} - \dfrac{1}{3}(\nabla \cdot \mathbf{u})\mathbb{I}$.

This expression can be further simplified in two cases:

- incompressible flow, $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{u} = 0$
  $\mathbb{D}^d = \mathbb{D}\quad\rightarrow\quad\mathbb{S} = 2 \mu \mathbb{D}$
- monoatomic compressible gas, with Stokes' assumption, i.e. $\dfrac{2}{3}\mu + \lambda =0$

In these case we can write the vector stress

$\mathbf{t_{n}} = -p\mathbf{\hat{n}} + \mathbf{s_{n}} = -p\mathbf{\hat{n}} + 2 \mu \mathbf{d_{n}}$,

Introducing a Cartesian reference frame on a flat fixed surface, with $x$, $y$ parallel, $z$ orthogonal to to the wall at $z=0$, we can evaluate the stress vector for an incompressible flow at wall using the boundary conditions $\mathbf{u}(x,y,0)=\mathbf{0}$, as

$\mathbf{t_{n}} = \mu \dfrac{\partial u_x}{\partial z}\mathbf{\hat{x}} + \mu \dfrac{\partial u_y}{\partial z}\mathbf{\hat{y}} -p\mathbf{\hat{z}}$

Comment: It is not correct to say that then normal component of $\mathbf{t_n}$ is minus the pressure.  There is also a viscous contribution.

Comment: @ChetMiller over a flat fixed surface, for an incompressible flow $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{u} = \partial_x u_x + \partial_y u_y + \partial_z u_z = 0$, that contribution would read $\partial_z u_z = - \partial_x u_x - \partial_y u_y = 0$, because $u_x = u_y = 0$ at wall and thus $\partial_{i} u_x = \partial_i u_y = 0$ at wall, in any direction $i = x, y$ describing the wall.

Comment: That's only if it's a solid surface with a non-slip BC.  Also, for a monoatomic gas, $\lambda=0$.

Comment: Most of the solid surfaces in real like have no-slip conditions on it

Comment: Like I said. The equation applies only on a solid surface. It does not apply on an area  internal to the fluid.

Answer (score 1):

In general, shear stress is the off-diagonal term of the stress *tensor*.

$$ {\boldsymbol \sigma} = \begin{bmatrix} \sigma_{xx} & \tau_{xy} & \tau_{xz} \\  \tau_{xy} & \sigma_{yy} & \tau_{yz} \\ \tau_{xz} & \tau_{yz} & \sigma_{zz}
\end{bmatrix} $$

They do not behave like vectors at all. For example, rotations require a congruent transformation

$$ \boldsymbol{\sigma} = \mathrm{R}\, \boldsymbol{\sigma}' \,\mathrm{R}^\intercal $$

where $\mathrm{R}$ is the 3×3 orthogonal matrix.

To find the "magnitude" of the stress tensor, you need a stress theory, such as Tresca or [whatever would be appropriate for fluids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viscous_stress_tensor).

Answer (score -4):

Yes, it is a vector. When you look at a basic definition, i.e. a force per unit area, which is parallel to the force, it is basically vector divided by scalar, which is vector.

Comment: This is *very* far from a complete answer. Stress is a tensor, since it is force per unit area and needs to take account of the orientation of the area. For isotropic pressure this can be ignored, but in solids the area cannot be thought of as a scalar, and must instead be treated as a vector.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Stress is tensor, but isn't shear stress just a vector? You are right about the orientation of the area.

Comment: Shear stress typically refers to the off-diagonal components of the stress tensor.

Comment: Shear stress is definitely not a vector, and to add it up with sum-squares _assumes_ not only orthogonal faces but also equal area faces.